# Performing KNN using the class package with odd values of k between 1 and 21 (inclusive) in R

Tags: r, knn

I am trying to perform KNN on the iris dataset with odd values of k between 1 - 21 (inclusive). However, I am getting an error. Here is what I have tried...

```
data(iris)

# 80% of data training data.
ran <- sample(1:nrow(iris), 0.8 * nrow(iris)) 

# Normalization function.
nor <-function(x) { (x -min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)) }
# Run nomalization on columns 3 and 4 - the predictors.
iris_norm <- as.data.frame(lapply(iris[,c(3,4)], nor))

summary(iris_norm)
Petal.Length     Petal.Width     
Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.00000  
1st Qu.:0.1017   1st Qu.:0.08333  
Median :0.5678   Median :0.50000  
Mean   :0.4675   Mean   :0.45806  
3rd Qu.:0.6949   3rd Qu.:0.70833  
Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.00000  

# extract training set
iris_train <- iris_norm[ran,] 
# extract testing set
iris_test <- iris_norm[-ran,] 

# extract 5th column of train dataset because it will be used as 'cl' argument in knn function.
iris_target_category <- iris[ran,5]
# extract 5th column if test dataset to measure the accuracy.
iris_test_category <- iris[-ran,5]

# Get all odd numbers 1 - 59 (inclusive).
odd_k_1_21 <- seq(1, 21, 2)

# run knn function
predict <- knn(iris_train,iris_test,cl=iris_target_category,k=odd_k_1_21)
```

The warning I am getting is due to the value of k I entered and this is the warning

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (ntr < k) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (k < 1) stop(gettextf("k = %d must be at least 1", k), domain = NA) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Is there a way to remove this error or a more effective way of just choosing odd values between 1 - 21?

**Update:**

```
trctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
set.seed(3333)
knn_fit <- train(iris_target_category ~ ., data = iris_train, method = "knn", trControl=trctrl, preProcess = c("center", "scale"), tuneLength = 10)
```

but getting error `Error in [.data.frame (data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected`

Comment: In the line that is failing,  you call the result `predict`, but the function `knn` does not produce predictions itself.  It produces a model (to which you can apply the `predict` function). What are you trying to get? 11 models or 11 sets of predictions?

Comment: @G5W I am trying to perform knn to get a model. After this line I have created a confusion matrix to get the accuracy of this... confusionMatrix(table(pr ,training_items_test_category))

Comment: This feels like an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion if you are struggling with machine learning in R, it is better to use caret packages, because this packages can provide a lot of models in machine learning area such as K- Nearest Neighbor. At first it is a little complicated using this packages but when you will learn it, you are going to be master in machine learning. This link I think can be helpful to you:
https://dataaspirant.com/2017/01/09/knn-implementation-r-using-caret-package/

```
rm(list = ls())
library(caret)
data(iris)

# 80% of data training data.
ran <- sample(1:nrow(iris), 0.8 * nrow(iris)) 

# Normalization function.
nor <-function(x) { (x -min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)) }
# Run nomalization on columns 3 and 4 - the predictors.
iris_norm <- as.data.frame(lapply(iris[,c(3,4)], nor))
# extract training set
iris_train <- iris_norm[ran,] 
# extract testing set
iris_test <- iris_norm[-ran,] 

# extract 5th column of train dataset because it will be used as 'cl' 
argument in knn function.
iris_target_category <- factor(iris[ran,5])
iris_data_train <- cbind(iris_target_category,iris_train)
# extract 5th column if test dataset to measure the accuracy.
iris_test_category <- factor(iris[-ran,5])
iris_data_test <- cbind(iris_test_category,iris_test)
trctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
set.seed(3333)
knn_fit <- train(iris_target_category ~ ., data = iris_data_train, method = 
                 "knn",
             trControl=trctrl, 
             preProcess = c("center", "scale"), tuneLength = 10)
```

Comment: I have tried performing knn with a train control etc. but I am getting the error `Error in [.data.frame(data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected`. See edit in my question to see what I tried.

Comment: check the edited comment. this is correct. you did a little mistake in your code. I hope it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I also think the tidymodels packages might help you out:

```
data(iris)
library(tidymodels)

iris_split <- initial_split(iris,prop = .8)
iris_training <- iris_split %>% training()
iris_testing <- iris_split %>% testing()

iris_recipe <- iris_training %>% 
  recipe(Species ~ .) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_predictors())


#devtools::install_github("tidymodels/tune")

library(tune)
iris_mod <- 
  nearest_neighbor(neighbors = tune()) %>% 
  set_engine("kknn") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

library(workflows)
iris_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(iris_mod) %>% 
  add_recipe(iris_recipe)


iris_param <- 
  iris_wflow %>% 
  parameters() %>% 
  update(
    neighbors = neighbors(range = c(1,21)),
  )

ctrl <- control_grid(verbose = TRUE)
set.seed(42)

cv_splits <- iris_training %>% vfold_cv(v = 5)

knn_search <- tune_grid(iris_wflow,
                         resamples  = cv_splits,
                         param_info = iris_param,
                         grid = 30,
                         control = ctrl,
                         metrics = metric_set(roc_auc,accuracy))

p <- knn_search %>% autoplot()
p %>% plotly::ggplotly()
```